# Efficient/Pythonic way to Filter pandas DataFrame based on priority

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe.

```
+-----------+----------+-----+
| InvoiceNo | ItemCode | Qty |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-001  |     A    |  2  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-001  |     B    |  3  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-001  |     C    |  1  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-002  |     B    |  3  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-002  |     D    |  4  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-003  |     C    |  3  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-003  |     D    |  9  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-004  |     D    |  5  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-004  |     E    |  8  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
|  Inv-005  |     X    |  2  |
+-----------+----------+-----+
```

my task is to create an additional column `Type` based on the priority of the item occurrence.

eg: `ItemCode A` has `1st` Priority. then `B` has `2nd` priority and `C` has `3rd` priority. rest of the items has `least` priority and classified has `Other`.

So, if any Invoice contains item `A`, the type should be `Type - A` irrespective other items presence. from the balance Invoices if item `B` contains, then the type should be `Type - B`. same for `C`. if none of `A, B or C` is not present in any invoice, then the type should be `Type - Other`.

Below is my desired output.

```
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
| InvoiceNo | ItemCode | Qty |     Type     |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-001  |     A    |  2  |   Type - A   |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-001  |     B    |  3  |   Type - A   |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-001  |     C    |  1  |   Type - A   |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-002  |     B    |  3  |   Type - B   |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-002  |     D    |  4  |   Type - B   |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-003  |     C    |  3  |   Type - C   |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-003  |     D    |  9  |   Type - C   |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-004  |     D    |  5  | Type - Other |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-004  |     E    |  8  | Type - Other |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
|  Inv-005  |     X    |  2  | Type - Other |
+-----------+----------+-----+--------------+
```

Below is my code and it works. But, it is more cumbersome and not `pythonic` at all.

```
# load Dataframe
df = pd.read_excel() 

# filter data containing `A`
mask_A = (df['ItemCode'] == 'A').groupby(df['InvoiceNo']).transform('any')
df_A = df[mask_A]
df_A['Type'] = 'Type - A'

# form the rest of the data, filter data containing `B`
df = df[~mask_A]
mask_B = (df['ItemCode'] == 'B').groupby(df['InvoiceNo']).transform('any')
df_B = df[mask_B]
df_B['Type'] = 'Type - B'

# form the rest of the data, filter data containing `c`
df = df[~mask_B]
mask_C = (df['ItemCode'] == 'C').groupby(df['InvoiceNo']).transform('any')
df_C = df[mask_C]
df_C['Type'] = 'Type - C'

# form the rest of the data, filter data doesnt contain `A, B or C`
df_Other = df[~mask_C]
df_Other['Type'] = 'Type - Other'

# Conctenate all the dataframes
df = pd.concat([df_A, df_B, df_C, df_Other], axis=0,sort=False)
```

Now, what is the most `efficient` and `pythonic` way to do this?

Comment: In the future please do not use markdown tables, because they are not easily reproducible. Please see [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't use the invoice col

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like we can do `Categorical` then `transform`

```
df['Type']=pd.Categorical(df.ItemCode,['A','B','C'],ordered=True)

df['Type']='Type_'+df.groupby('InvoiceNo')['Type'].transform('min').fillna('other')
```

Update

```
df['Type']=pd.Categorical(df.ItemCode,['A','B','C'],ordered=True)
df=df.sort_values('Type')
df['Type']='Type_'+df.groupby('InvoiceNo')['Type'].transform('first').fillna('other')
df=df.sort_index()

df
Out[32]: 
     InvoiceNo ItemCode  Qty        Type
0    Inv-001          A    2      Type_A
1    Inv-001          B    3      Type_A
2    Inv-001          C    1      Type_A
3    Inv-002          B    3      Type_B
4    Inv-002          D    4      Type_B
5    Inv-003          C    3      Type_C
6    Inv-003          D    9      Type_C
7    Inv-004          D    5  Type_other
8    Inv-004          E    8  Type_other
9    Inv-005          X    2  Type_other
```